# How can i prevent tor from using /tmp

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor creates temp files in /tmp when downloading files, this is obliviously a security issue. How can i prevent Tor from using /tmp ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tor **does not** create it - it's daemon is just a network service. The browser - it's a *separate* binary, so - yes, you're right: it's a privacy leak indeed. To mitigate it use either a VM routed through Tor with a regular browser or use QubesOS with a disposable VM for that kind of tasks. If you have to use Tor browser in a routed VM - make sure that your Tor will use your another Tor instance to access the Tor network

Answer (score 0):

For convenience you could use [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/).

> 3.1 Private Mode
>
> Private mode is a quick way to hide all the files in your home
> directory from sandboxed programs. Enable it using --private command
> line option:
>
> ```
> $ firejail –private firefox
> ```
>
> Firejail mounts a temporary tmpfs filesystem on top of /home/user
> directory. Any files created in this directory will be deleted when
> you close the sandbox. You can also use an existing directory as home
> for your sandbox, allowing you to have a persistent home:
>
> ```
> $ firejail –private=~/my_private_dir firefox
> ```

If you already have an instance of Firefox running you can do this to test:

```
firejail --private firefox -no-remote
```

For the Tor browser you just need to adjust the executable path accordingly.